# IAM policy does not explicitly allow listing of S3 objects but I can still list them using this JavaScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Here is my policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/images/products/full-images/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/images/products/mediums/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/images/products/thumbs/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

As you can see, list objects permission is not listed. However, I can still list objects from these folders with this:

```
s3.listObjects({ Prefix: albumPhotosKey }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
        return alert("There was an error viewing your album: " + err.message);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

How can I prevent the listing of objects on these folders? I only want permission to upload to them, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to edit the ACL and remove List access for the public.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that any future readers with the same question can learn from it.